# Writing Countif and xlookup formulas into VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This week I have started learning to use VBA macros so I apologies in advance if I get the terminology wrong.

I have recorded my macro in Excel and it "works' however it takes a long time to run and on occasion crash. I think the issue might be that I have a number of IfCountifs and Xlookup formulas in the macro.

Is there a more efficient way to write the following formulas:

```
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        Range("H7").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!C[-7],Sheet2!RC[-7],'Sheet1!C[1],""*Text*""), ""Text"", ""Text"")"
        Range("H7").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H7:H" & lr)
    
        Range("K7").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
            "=XLOOKUP(1,('Sheet1'!C[-10]=Sheet2!RC[-10])*('Sheet1!C[-1]=""Text""), 'Sheet1'!C[1], """")"
        Range("K7").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K7:K" & lr)
```

In Excel the formulas look like this:

```
    =IF(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A:A,Data!A7,'Sheet1'!I:I,"*Text*"), "Text", "Text")
    =XLOOKUP(1,('Sheet1'!A:A=Sheet2!A7)*('Sheet1'!J:J="Text"), 'Sheet1'!L:L, "")
```

The macro 'works' but it is really slow and occasionally crashes.

Comment: Specify the Sheet name to the Range object and to the ActiveCell also, because without that, it refers to the activesheet object. This can cause the crashes.

Comment: In case of Activecell it means that prior select the required sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Write Formulas Using VBA

[image]

- You should avoid using entire columns to look up data.
- You should consider putting the data into Excel (structured) tables. Then formulas with structured references would ensure it to be dynamic and all this VBA business wouldn't be necessary.

```vb
Sub WriteFormulas()
    
    Const SRC_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2 ' adjust!!!
    
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As Long = 7
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim srg As Range, sLastRow As Long
    
    With wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET)
        sLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set srg = .Range(.Cells(SRC_FIRST_ROW, "A"), .Cells(sLastRow, "A"))
    End With
    
    ' Sheet
    Dim sSheet As String: sSheet = "'" & SRC_SHEET & "'!"
    ' Lookup
    Dim SL1 As String: SL1 = sSheet & srg.Address
    Dim SL2 As String: SL2 = sSheet & srg.EntireRow.Columns("I").Address
    Dim SL3 As String: SL3 = sSheet & srg.EntireRow.Columns("J").Address
    ' Return
    Dim SR3 As String: SR3 = sSheet & srg.EntireRow.Columns("L").Address
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim drg As Range, dLastRow As Long
    
    With wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
        dLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set drg = .Range(.Cells(DST_FIRST_ROW, "A"), .Cells(dLastRow, "A"))
    End With
    
    ' lookup
    Dim DL1 As String: DL1 = drg.Cells(1).Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Formulas
    
    ' =IF(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A:A,A7,'Sheet1'!I:I,"*Text*"),"Yes", "No")
    With drg.Columns("H")
        .Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(" & SL1 & "," & DL1 & "," & SL2 _
            & ",""*Text*""),""Yes"",""No"")"
    End With
    
    ' =XLOOKUP(1,(Sheet1!A:A=A7)*(Sheet1!J:J="Text"),Sheet1!L:L,"")
    With drg.Columns("K")
        .Formula2 = "=XLOOKUP(1,(" & SL1 & "=" & DL1 & ")*(" _
        & SL3 & "=""Text"")," & SR3 & ","""")"
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Formulas written.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It has sped up the process significantly. I will make sure that I utilise tables moving forward.